# What is the best way to compare images in a 2 picturebox?

Tags: c#, image, comparison, picturebox

Currently I'm developing remote access application using c#. So that I need to compare 2 images loaded in to Picturebox Image property. What is the best and fast way to compare these images. Please guide me. (I'm a new to C#)

Comment: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/39987/10972

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/374386/Simple-image-comparison-in-NET